# Problema no setListData

Tags: java, swing

Fiz o exemplo do livro "Java Como programar".

Estou tendo problema na linha **copyJList.setListData(colorJList.getSelectedValue());**

Alguém poderia ajudar.

```
package LvProg8.exercicio.capitulo14.exemp8;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MultipleSelectionFrame extends JFrame {
    private JList colorJList; //lista para exibir cores
    private JList copyJList;
    private JButton copyJButton;
    private static final String[] colorNames = {
            "Black", "Blue", "Cyan", "Dark Gray", "Gray", "Green", "Light Gray", "Magenta"
            , "Orange", "Pink", "Red", "White", "Yellow"
    };

    //Contrutor
    public MultipleSelectionFrame()
    {
        super("Multiplas seleções");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        colorJList = new JList(colorNames);
        colorJList.setVisibleRowCount(5); //
        colorJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        System.out.println(colorJList.getSelectedValue());

        //adiciona JScrollPane que contem JList ao frame
        add(new JScrollPane(colorJList));

        copyJButton = new JButton("Copy >>>");
        copyJButton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        copyJList.setListData(colorJList.getSelectedValue());
                    }
                }
        );
        add(copyJButton);

        copyJList = new JList();
        copyJList.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        copyJList.setFixedCellWidth(100);
        copyJList.setFixedCellHeight(15);
        copyJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(copyJList));
    }
}
```

---

Esta dando este erro:

> Error:(35, 34) java: no suitable method found for
>   setListData(java.lang.Object)
>       method javax.swing.JList.setListData(java.lang.Object[]) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[])
>       method javax.swing.JList.setListData(java.util.Vector) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Vector)

---

Selecionar os itens da lista para atribuir a outra lista, todo vez que clica no botão gera o erro

[image: Selecionar os itens]

Comment: Qual é o erro que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 1):

Como pode ser visto na documentação, o método [`setListData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData-E:A-) espera receber ou um array ou um tipo `Vector`, e com `colorJList.getSelectedValue()` você não está passando nenhum dos dois tipos.

Destaco da documentação do método [`getSelectedValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue--):

> Retorna o valor para o menor índice de célula selecionado; o valor selecionado quando apenas um único item é selecionado na lista. Quando vários itens são selecionados, é simplesmente o valor do menor índice selecionado. Retorna *null* se não houver seleção.

Você não deu nenhuma explicação adicional, por isso não tem como nem sugerir nada de correção, por isso é importante sempre fornecer um contexto pro problema e não apenas o erro e o código.

É sempre importante também verificar a documentação do método, quase sempre a leitura evita esse tipo de erro de tipo.

Comment: Pensei que isso mantivesse o array...: colorJList = new JList(colorNames);

Comment: @WelitonFigueiredo voce chegou a ler a documentaçao do método getselectedValue? É importante ler a documentacao dos metodos antes de usa-lo, nele explica o que este metodo retorna.

Comment: Entendi que retorna uma lista do que esta sendo selecionado dentro da lista

Comment: @WelitonFigueiredo destaco da [**documentaçao**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue--): `Retorna o valor para o menor índice de célula selecionado; o valor selecionado quando apenas um único item é selecionado na lista. Quando vários itens são selecionados, é simplesmente o valor do menor índice selecionado. Retorna nullse não houver seleção.`. Está vendo? Retorna apenas um indice selecionado, nao retorna lista, acho que voce compreendeu mal o metodo

Comment: Entendi que setListData, precisa ser uma array, então fiz isso para funcionar: Object[] objects = colorJList.getSelectedValuesList().toArray();